# ObjectiveC - get pixels location of CGImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, pixel

I am trying to loop trough the pixels of a `CGImage` and get the point location of each pixel. I have managed to count all the pixels but I cannot figure out how to get the point of each pixel.

How could I achieve this?

```
+ (NSUInteger) getPixelsOfImage:(UIImage*)image {


    // 1. Get pixels of image
    CGImageRef inputCGImage = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage);

    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

    UInt32 * pixels;
    pixels = (UInt32 *) calloc(height * width, sizeof(UInt32));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), inputCGImage);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);


    NSUInteger pixelsCount = 0;

    UInt32 * currentPixel = pixels;
    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < width; i++) {

                pixelsCount++;

            currentPixel++;
        }
    }

    free(pixels);

    return pixelsCount;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "the point location of each pixel"? It's just (x, y) where x is the horizontal coordinate and y is the vertical. In your loop, it would be (i, j). Is that all you're asking?

Comment: Sorry. I want to get the coordinate of each pixel so I can select them

Comment: The coordinate relative to what? I already told you what the coordinate relative to the image itself is. The image is just an in-memory object. There's no "real-world" position for its pixels to be relative to. What does "select them" mean? You really need to give specifics about what a solution might look like and how you would use it?